# Trying to print a big string in go

Tags: security, go

I'm trying to print a java secure integer saved in a database, this is an example:
i have this:

```golang
salt := "fqm0vp02103inkmvb18cgqbv0s9v7o43o12hj0nhj9jqit8nh327re7iup2imdtedepch8alam8340u4rcd923g9nuubh3a4jbdonr67phej9fp9oitudnp3dabi09nr"
fmt.Printf(salt)
```

this is what i got in go, but i need the string as it is in the database:

```
66716d3076703032313033696e6b6d76623138636771627630733976376f34336f3132686a306e686a396a716974386e6833323772653769757032696d647465646570636838616c616d38333430753472636439323367396e757562683361346a62646f6e7236377068656a396670396f697475646e70336461626930396e72
```

Comment: Ok, and what code made you get that, and what did you expect to get?

Comment: The output is the hexadecimal representation of the ascii character values that comprise the string (f = 66, q = 71 ...).  This is unanswerable without more detail.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I want to print that string but the output is that

Comment: @SantiagoUmañaVillada: no, it's not: https://play.golang.org/p/UudsDlRNul.  Please show a complete example, including what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, you just need to hex encode your string and will will match:

https://play.golang.org/p/p4XLYd0smZ

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/hex"
)

func main() {
    salt := "fqm0vp02103inkmvb18cgqbv0s9v7o43o12hj0nhj9jqit8nh327re7iup2imdtedepch8alam8340u4rcd923g9nuubh3a4jbdonr67phej9fp9oitudnp3dabi09nr"
    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString([]byte(salt)))
}
```